# SqlDataReader prints multiple rows, how can I split?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I want to retrieve data from a DB using a `SqlDataReader`. I got it working but my query return more than one row of data and I want to separate it.

Here is my code

```
string query = "select title, rating, dor from movie where title like '%"+name+"%';";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Response.Write(reader[0].ToString());
            Response.Write(reader[1].ToString());
            Response.Write(reader[2].ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("No rows found");
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

So for example.. `reader[0].ToString()` is the title, since it is returning more than one row of data it prints "title1title2". Is there a way to split this so title from row 1 is separate from the title from row 2?

Comment: I'm not seeing how your code produces the output you are describing.  You should be getting `rating` and `dor` values as well.

Comment: Yes, it produces those as well I am just using the title as the example in the description.

Comment: Well, it's confusing if you post some code, and then post an output that doesn't match the code.  I'm assuming you are supposed to be writing some HTML?  Then just add the appropriate HTML markup to add new lines between each loop iteration, like `<br/>`

Comment: Add a Response.WriteLine() in while loop.

Comment: Sstan, Response.Write(reader[0].ToString()) alone is returning two titles, from two different entries in the dB. That one line is printing "title1title2" I want to split that.

Comment: Use

'Response.WriteLine()'

After
'Response.Write(reader[2].ToString());'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string query = "select title, rating, dor from movie where title like '%"+name+"%';";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Response.Write(reader[0].ToString());
            Response.Write(reader[1].ToString());
            Response.Write(reader[2].ToString());
            Response.Write("------------------------");//whatever separator you want to use
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("No rows found");
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```